# running the singularity image and finding the results

Tags: singularity-container

I am trying to make the image for the Singularity using the following file(which is `Singularity.recepie`):

```
Bootstrap: docker
From: ubuntu:18.04


%post
        apt-get -y update
        apt-get install -y python3-pip


%files
        QC.py /


%runscript
        python3 /QC.py
```

I build the image using the following command:

```
sudo singularity build ubuntu.simg Singularity.recepie
```

and run the image using this command:

```
./ubuntu.simg
```

when I run the image it works but I do not see the result files in the directory that I am working at. do you know how I can the results and copy them to my current directory?

Answer (score 1):

By default, your current working directory is mounted into the image and used as the working directory. If no files are being created and they should be, then you need to look at where your script is trying to write to. Also check the singularity error/warnings output for additional info.

If you're using an older version of Singularity (implied by `.simg` instead of `.sif` extension), you may also be running on a kernel that does not support overlayfs, which can cause issues attempting to mount to a non-existing folder. If this is the case, singularity will give a warning but continue on and possibly fail in a hard to detect manner. [More info on mounting with overlay here](https://sylabs.io/guides/2.6/user-guide/bind_paths_and_mounts.html#binding-with-overlay).